# Multi level columns manipulation in dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask dataframe where I applied many aggregations using `agg` method. The  result is a dataframe with multilevel columns. Is there a way to manipulate the produced columsn from the aggregations?

```
grouped_ddf = ddf.groupby('col1').agg({'col2':['min', 'max', 'sum']})
# how to I access col2.min and col2.max independantly.
```

Is there a way to have them automatically renamed to something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to the pandas 0.25 official documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you have the following function arguments and keyword arguments available.

```py
DataFrame.groupby(self, by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=False, observed=False, **kwargs)
```

So there is no automatic way it seems to me. However you can save it and rename it but I guess that will not serve your purpose. Best wishes